# Is python copy(another_obj) equivalent to object().__dict__.update(antoher_obj.__dict__)?

Tags: python

Looks like both [copy function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) and `object().__dict__.update()` would make a same shallow copy of attributes within another object.

Can I think the both approaches are equivalent in python?

```
obj = copy(another_obj)
```

Is equivalent to code below?:

```
obj = object().__dict__.update(another_obj.__dict__)
```

**Edit:**
The second command above does not work actually.
It should be revised as below:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

another_obj = Foo()
another_obj.att1 = "value1"
```

duplicate with copy():

```
obj1 = copy(another_obj)
```

duplicate with __dict__.update()

```
obj2 = Foo()
obj2.__dict__.update(another_obj.__dict__)
```

The content of both obj1 and obj2 are same:

```
>>> dir(obj1) == dir(obj2)
True
```

Does it mean obj1 is equivalent to obj2?

Comment: It's pretty easy to just fire up the interpreter and try it. If the results are the same, the snippets might be equivalent. If the results are different, the snippets definitely aren't equivalent. Try it and see what you get.

Comment: The second code won't even work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so

```
obj = copy(another_obj)
```

Creates a new object to copy new attributes to.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2>hi</h2>')
soup2 = copy(soup)
print(soup2.__dict__)
```

> prints lots of stuff

But with

```
obj = object().__dict__.update(another_obj.__dict__)
```

You'd need to do some extra work to get the copy done

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h2>hi</h2>')
blank_object = BeautifulSoup()
soup2 = blank_object.__dict__.update(soup.__dict__)
print(soup2.__dict__)
```

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**dict**'

Got me wondering though

Comment: Since `blank_object.__dict__.update(soup.__dict__)` is a statement but expression, hence it will return None but blank_object . That means soup2 = None.